# Error while passing abstract class pointer in derived class constructor

Tags: c++, function, class, inheritance, virtual

> SoftwareDownload is derived class.
> Implemented defination for virtual function from abstract class-**da::skeleton::ServiceInterface_DMwithDASkeleton**
> please find code below.Have edited code.
> Trying to pass abstract class pointer in derviced class contructor.

class **SoftwareDownload**: **public** da::skeleton::**ServiceInterface_DMwithDASkeleton**
{
using DA_Skeleton= da::skeleton::ServiceInterface_DMwithDASkeleton;

```
protected:
    
da::skeleton::ServiceInterface_DMwithDASkeleton *DA_Skeleton_ptr;
   
public:

**SoftwareDownload**(da::skeleton::ServiceInterface_DMwithDASkeleton *DA_Skeleton_ptr ,ara::com::InstanceIdentifier instance_id ,ara::com::MethodCallProcessingMode mode);
  
  virtual ~**SoftwareDownload**();
 <ReturnType> **RequestToDownload**(const std::uint32_t& SID,const std::uint32_t& size)override;
 <ReturnType> **TransferData**(const std::uint32_t& SID,const std::uint32_t& Payload_Data)override;
  
}

//SoftwareDownload Constructor . Trying to initialise abstract class pointer.

**SoftwareDownload**::**SoftwareDownload**(da::skeleton::ServiceInterface_DMwithDASkeleton *DA_Skeleton_ptr ,ara::com::InstanceIdentifier instance_id ,ara::com::MethodCallProcessingMode mode)
   :**DA_Skeleton**(instance_id ,mode)
{
    //Initialize SoftwareDownload Skeleton for service instance 1

   **DA_Skeleton_ptr** = new DA_Skeleton(ara::com::InstanceIdentifier(1),ara::com::MethodCallProcessingMode::kEvent);
}

**SoftwareDownload**::~**SoftwareDownload**()=default;


//abstract Class

class **ServiceInterface_DMwithDASkeleton** : public da::ServiceInterface_DMwithDA, public ara::com::internal::skeleton::TypedServiceImplBase<ServiceInterface_DMwithDASkeleton> {

public:
**ServiceInterface_DMwithDASkeleton**(ara::com::InstanceIdentifier instance_id, ara::com::MethodCallProcessingMode mode = ara::com::MethodCallProcessingMode::kEvent) : ara::com::internal::skeleton::TypedServiceImplBase<ServiceInterface_DMwithDASkeleton>(instance_id, mode) {}

virtual ~**ServiceInterface_DMwithDASkeleton**() 
  { 
      //
  }
    
**virtual** <ReturnType> **RequestToDownload**(const std::uint32_t& SID,const std::uint32_t& size) = 0;
**virtual** <ReturnType> **TransferData**(const std::uint32_t& SID,const std::uint32_t& Payload_Data) = 0;
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to instantiate the abstract class.`da::skeleton::ServiceInterface_DMwithDASkeleton` somewhere. You've included too little code for me to say where though. Please post a [mre]

Comment: @TedLyngmo .Please find full code.

Comment: Please post _real_ code. It's impossible to read or compile what you put in the question now. Make a [mre].

Comment: I'm voting to close this question now since you haven't provided more information.

Answer (score 0):

`ServiceInterface_DMwithDASkeleton` is an abstract class. It can't be instantiated.

Yet, you're trying to do just that:

```
using DA_Skeleton = da::skeleton::ServiceInterface_DMwithDASkeleton;

// ...

DA_Skeleton_ptr = new DA_Skeleton(...);
```

Which is why you get an error.